# Должен ли сервер бесконечно получать сообщения?

Tags: java, клиент-сервер

Сделал простой клиент-сервер. Сделал цикл

```
while (connected) {
            try {
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fromClient.getInputStream()));
                System.out.print("Message got: " + in.toString() + "\n");
                out = new PrintWriter(fromClient.getOutputStream(), true);
                System.out.print("Message sent: " + out.toString() + "\n");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.print("Cannot get input stream from client\n");
            }
        }
```

Правильно ли это технически? Можно ли сделать чтобы сервер выполнял, только если клиент отправляет сообщение? Или просто поставить `Thread.sleep(1000);`

---

И еще такой вопрос. Нужно ли пересоздавать сокет. Или сделать его глобальной статической переменной?

Comment: думаю правильно. на то он и сервер, что бы сидеть и ждать:)

Comment: код сокращен настолько, что хочется сказать "да ну бред". Чтения и записи в сокет в коде нет (а чтение вызовом `InputStream.read` блокирующее, поэтому "сервер выполнял, только если клиент" получится само), какой сокет вы собираетесь пересоздавать - тоже непонятно.

Answer (score 1):

вполне достаточно 
`Thread.sleep(200)`. у тебя бесконечный цикл, так как connected никогда не меняет статус. Если есть метод проверяющий коннект, то пусти его в отдельном потоке.
а внутри реализуй получения статуса

`connected = fromClient.isConnected();
 Thread.sleep(200)`

Comment: `connected` меняет статус. Это я привел код без "воды". На самом деле я вообще заменил `BufferedReader` и `PrintWriter` на `InputStream` и `OutputStream` соответственно. И если в `InputStream` текст `"Exit"` то `connected = false` и цикл завершается. Спасибо за ответ. Еще бы узнать нужно ли пересоздавать сокет

Comment: не вижу смысла в пересоздании сокета, особенно на сервере